# Algorithm/Data structure name request: fixed size array with increasing stride on overwrite

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, naming

I'm looking for a "cannonical" name of a data structure with the characteristics below. I can implement it with a little thought given my application, but I'm curious if there's a matching data structure type or algorithm that's been studied in the past.

Requirements:

1. Fixed size array backing
2. Writing uses monotonically increasing strides in the following sense:

   The array is filled from start to finish with single index             increases until the array is filled. E.g. given an integer i = 0 and an unchanging fixed size integer n, the array is filled with i++ until i = n.

   The index is then reset to the second element (index 1), so i =  1. The stride thus increases by a value of 1; in general the stride will increase by 1 each time the array bound is met or overshot. For the first time the stride is increased, instead of i++ we have i = i + 2 until i >= n.

   ```
   int sRes=0;
   template<T>
   void addElement(T* element)
   {
       if(i >= n)
       {
           if (stride > 2*n)
           { 
               sRes++;
               // keep stride from overflowing the integer type
               stride = (stride mod n);
           }
           stride += 1; 
           i = stride mod n; 
       }
       // array of AR type, AR defined in #3 below
       array[i] = new AR(element, stride);
       i += stride;
   }
   ```
3. Array elements include the "stride value" when the entry was written/overwritten. Thus I can determine what stride the current element was written under. Thus we may define an array element as:

   ```
   template<T> struct AR
   {
       T* value;
       int stride;
   }
   ```
4. Array reads respect the random-access model (e.g. any index may be read at anytime, due to the under-laying array).

To me, this has a few issues; if I want to know the current stride, I can look it up in the array. But at some point I will have strides that vary between n and 2*n. While this seems suited to the task above, I'm wondering about the implications. I'm operating on an embedded device, with little memory. I want some notion on how long I've gone updating the array. I could save the number of times I've modded, with further logic to reduce the necessary meta information on the stride value, like making the current mod count a static; the mod count being the number of times I've increased the stride.

Thus the interest I have in a name might include observations like the mod issue as presented. I can store the current number of stride increases in an int32. Under my constraints, this is acceptable; though I like using the proper name of an idea if it exists and I like reading about observations I may have missed.

I hope this presentation of the issue is understandable! If not, let me know and I'll update accordingly.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you outline the advantages of this data structure? I have a hard time imagining it as something that people would want to do. Especially, what are you doing with all the empty space in the stride>1 case?

Comment: @NicoSchertler The stride increments once the array becomes filled. An invariant: the stride increments once the array has been filled. At that point overwriting of previously filled elements occurs. The striding is meant to keep values over the course of a time that the data in the structure cannot be transferred to some other place. Imagine a Fitbit, it logs data over the course of operation. At some point the memory becomes filled. Instead of erasing the memory and retaining the initial granularity of data collection, we want to coarsen the data collection rate. Hope that helps!